# Comparing Self-Report Data to Binary results

Tags: regression, logistic, correlation, t-test, pearson-r

I have two sets of data: DES scores (self-report) and whether dissociation was experienced during an experiment (yes or no). My sample size is 83 (71 no, 12 yes). I want to know if high DES scores are related to those 12 people experiencing dissociation.

To my understanding this means I have a discrete independent variable and a binary dependent variable. Is that right?

What would be the best way to compare these?

I have an feeling independent t-test or Pearson correlation would be wrong. Would I need to do a logistic regression?

Comment: You want to compare two means - why do you consider t-test inappropriate?

Comment: @Tim Because that would be treating the self-report score as the dependent variable

Answer (score 0):

You should try a logistic regression, although the number of cases is low, so do not expect to much. You should also **show the data**, visualize, plot it. A stripchart with two lines would be nice, an example can be seen here:  [How can I draw a boxplot without boxes in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21370/how-can-i-draw-a-boxplot-without-boxes-in-r/21371#21371)